# Cannot fetch list of UIDs inside "users" collection in firebase using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users:[]
    };
  }

//method to get the data from users collection
  async componentDidMount() {
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      db.collection("users")
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
          const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
          console.log(data);
          this.setState({ users: data });
      })
      .catch( err =>{
          console.log(err);
      });
    }
```

this function returning an empty error
i want to print list of users uid

[image: firebase snippet]

here i have users collection and inside it i have retailers collection and its document

Comment: What error are you seeing, and where? What does the `console.log(data);` return? Can you add a `console.log(querySnapshot );`?

Comment: i got an array of length 0  instead of the documents... data coming from the query snapshot is stored into the data variable..so it supposed to display the list of documents.. i have used console.log(querySnapshot) it was also showing array of 0 length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you have to realize here is that *your users collection contains no documents*.  The document IDs are shown in italics, which means that there is no document here.  The IDs are visible because there is a nested subcollection under each document.  They are shown like this in the console so that you can click through and navigate to the nested subcollection, despite the document being missing.

If you want to list users with a query, you will have to actually create documents in the users collection.  They can be empty if you don't have any information.  **But you do need actual documents in the users collection in order for anything to show up in a query.**

Comment: sir i have fixed it.. now how can i list theUIDs from users into the table..

Answer (score 0):

This line in your current code `querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())` takes the **data** of each document. But you're keeping the UID in the **ID** of each document, so you'll want to use:

```
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  db.collection("users")
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
      const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.id);
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({ users: data });
  })
  .catch( err =>{
      console.log(err);
  });
```

---

**Update**: As Doug pointed out in his answer, if there are no actual user documents, your `get()` call will not return it.
I highly recommend creating user documents, even if it's just an empty one.

For now, the only way to get the UID would be to load all `retailers` for all users, and then use those results to get the ID of the parent documents:

```
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  db.collectiongroup("retailers")
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log("retailed "+doc.id+" for user "+doc.ref.parent.parent.id);
      });
  })
  .catch( err =>{
      console.log(err);
  });
```

You'll have to deduplicate the UIDs, but that will leads to getting the UIDs.

But you'll be loading all retailers for all users this way, so as said, I highly recommend storing a small/empty user document instead.

Comment: still i m getting an array of length 0 . i want to print all the UIDs of retailers collection

Comment: Each user has their own `retailers` collection. Do you want to show the retailers for a specific user (and if so, which one), or for all of them?

Comment: i want to list the users for now.. i want to show the retailers for the respective users in a different module

Comment: Ah, I now see. As Doug pointed out, if there are no actual user documents, the reading that collection will give no results.

Comment: yes sir... i have fixed it..but still cant print the UIDs.. although the length of users is now not 0

Answer (score 0):

The data method on querySnapshot.docs gets the data now to get the id of each document you need to add access the id property as UID is stored in id property

```
async componentDidMount() {
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      db.collection("users")
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
          const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().id);
          console.log(data);
          this.setState({ users: data });
      })
      .catch( err =>{
          console.log(err);
      });
    }
```